# What is meant by "an Easterly wind"?

Tags: boats, terminology, wind

Does it mean that the wind is coming *from* east *to* west. Or is it meaning that the wind is coming *from* west *to* east?

Comment: This question is not about what the front of the boat is, but what is meant by 'in the wind direction' which is perfectly answered in the first answer.

Comment: @MartinF the OP not having clarified, it was a noble move to change the question to disfavour your previous answer :)

Comment: @WeatherVane - Thank you. My only goal here is to get a reasonably written and unambiguous question, and *any* matching answer. I fear, however, the dust has not yet settled.

Comment: An Easterly Wind is a another way of saying "When the East Wind Blows". It was a saying during and directly after WWII referring to Rusian (Soviet Union) military forces. The saying became a novel in the late 1990s. Essentially it means the horror that comes when the Russian army comes from the East.

Comment: @Ron, except this is an outdoors site, not a history one.

Comment: @Darren Ron's comment was converted from an answer to the comment by a mod.

Answer (score 20):

Wind direction is, by convention, the direction that the wind is coming from. An easterly wind blows from east to west. If the bow of the boat is pointing into the wind, it's pointing to the east.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142080/discussion-on-answer-by-pete-becker-a-boat-is-mooring-we-say-the-front-of-the).

Answer (score 3):

One interpretation of the question, *in its original form*, was **What does the phrase "in the wind direction" mean?** This is an answer to that question.

The phrase "in the wind direction" is ambiguous.
It is not common terminology.
It could possibly mean either pointing "upwind", i.e., into the oncoming wind or pointing "downwind", i.e., in the same direction as the wind?

Given that a boat is moored, presumably away from any dock, then it is likely that it is pointing *into* the oncoming wind.

However, if there is significant water current present, then it is quite possible that the boat is pointing *upstream*, i.e., opposite to the water flow.